# Sequence of open balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have this excercise (that I am not sure if it is true):
Suppose $K$ is compact and
if $\left(B_{j}\right)_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of open balls that covers $K$, prove that there is a positive number $\epsilon$ such that each ball with radius $\epsilon$ and center $x \in K$ is contained in one of the balls $\left(B_{j}\right)_{j=1}^{\infty}$.

My attempt: As $K$ is a compact set, every open cover has a finite subcover, $(B_k)_{k=1}^N$, as it is finite we can consider the set of intersections of all balls, we can fit a ball of radius $\delta_i$ inside the $i$-th intersection, we can consider the minimum of the set of $\delta_i$ denote it $\bar{\delta}$, an consider $\epsilon = \frac{\bar{\delta}}{2}$. And let it be our epsilon.

I really feel that I am mising something, because I am not sure if the ball of radius $\epsilon$ will be completly contained inside one of the balls $(B_k)_{k=1}^N$, even on the the intersections (as close as I get to the "edge" of the intersection I am not sure if it garantees me to fit there). Am I wrong?

Comment: This is not so simple. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion is true. Every open cover of a compact metric space has a Lebesgue number, i.e., a number $\lambda>0$ such that every set of diameter less than $\lambda$ is contained in one of the sets of the cover.

Your argument, however, is incomplete because for every finite sub-cover that you choose I can come up with an open ball that will not fit in any of the intersections you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, that was what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

See in the initial open cover there are many open sets, and the delta you need to find is with respect to the initial open cover, so there may be a open set of radius delta that may not be inside some open set in the initial open cover.

More simply speaking there may be a $B_i$ that is not selected in the finite subcover and the radius is less than $\epsilon$ hence your epsilon might not necessarily work.

For a correct soln see Lebesgue number lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma)